# Cucumber throwing syntax error when not run via guard

Tags: ruby, cucumber, spork, guard

I'm getting a nasty syntax error when I try to run `bundle exec cucumber` or `rake cucumber`:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails31/gems/cucumber-1.1.4/lib/cucumber/js_support/js_dsl.js:3: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
```

As well as several other syntax errors from the same file. When I run the features via `bundle exec guard`, everything works fine.

I am using:

- Cucumber 1.1.4
- Rails 3.2
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Guard 1.0.0, guard-cucumber 0.7.5
- Spork 1.0.0rc2, guard-spork 0.5.2

This seems like some sort of compatibility problem but it's not apparent to me what the issue is. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same error, may be it's a bug, and we should report it ?

Comment: @SaidKaldybaev Unfortunately, the bug had already been reported, but closed as "Will not fix" by the Cucumber team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the tags syntax in my cucumber.yml file.

**Before**

```
std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} --strict --tags ~@wip ~@javascript"
```

**Fixed**

```
std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} --strict --tags ~@wip --tags ~@javascript"
```

I was not familiar with the `--tags` syntax. [Reference](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags)